# Postgres log_error_verbosity set to terse is not working. How to hide DETAIL and SQL from pgsql LOG

Tags: postgresql, logging

I have set `log_error_verbosity` to `terse` using below command

```
alter DATABASE abc_development SET log_error_verbosity to 'terse';
```

validated same with `show log_error_verbosity;` returning `terse`.

When i execute the query the log is displaying below details.

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_lower_email_text_unique_key"
DETAIL:  Key (lower(email::text), unique_key)=(admin-user@abc.in, 0) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "name", "uuid") values  ('admin-user@abc.in', '$2a$11$LauwBMBUwhF1NUZMqjQ9NuScki9rnoNdJb.t4pWdK5MjJm7KEmtsS', '2021-11-25 11:23:05.089084', '2021-11-25 11:23:05.089084', 'Praveen Kumar', 'L4iNSd')
```

I need only **ERROR**. But it is printing **DETAIL** and sql stmt which containing given data in logs.

How can i make sure only **ERROR** in log.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a parameter with `ALTER DATABASE` or `ALTER ROLE`, that will only become effective for new connections.

So you have to disconnect and reconnect for the change to take effect.

Comment: I have reconnected multiple times. still it is Printing DETAIL part in log

Comment: What do you get when you `SHOW log_error_verbosity`?

Comment: `terse` is  value shown

Comment: Then it will surely work. Perhaps the log comes from a different database. Or from an old session that is from before the change.